# Write a program to print the table of characters that are equivalent to the ASCII codes from 1 to 122. Only 10 chars per line

Tags: vb.net

I need help writing only 10 values per line of each code and making sure my code can efficiently put 10 ASCII equivalents for each line. I am lost and not sure where to start, any help or guidance in the correct direction is appreciated.

**Edit**

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Do While i <= 122
        Console.Write("{0,4}", Chr(i).ToString())
        If (i Mod 10 = 0) Then
            Console.WriteLine()
        End If
        i += 1
    Loop
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module
```

This is the code I have made however for the first two lines it does not print 10 characters and I am not sure why.

Comment: If you want to get help here, you need to be much more specific about the problems you are having.  If you are completely lost, you are better off asking your teacher for some guidance.

Comment: Maybe they're control characters and are not to be printed?

Comment: You are writing to the console, it emulates a teletype from the early 1970s.  Some of these characters mean special things to a teletype:  7 = bell (you can hear it), 8 = backspace, 9 = tab, 10 = line feed (note the extra line), 13 = carriage return.  Note how you cannot see 11 and 12, the carriage return caused them to be overwritten.  Your teacher almost surely meant for you to discover this so don't fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VS2015 on Windows 7, I modified your `Console.Write` to

```
Console.Write("{0:X2}:{1,-4}", i, Chr(i).ToString())
```

which shows the character code in hex as well as the character.

I got this output for the first few lines:

```
01:☺   02:☻   03:♥   04:♦   05:♣   06:♠   07:   08   09:           0A:

   0E:♫   0F:☼   10:►   11:◄   12:↕   13:‼   14:¶
15:§   16:▬   17:↨   18:↑   19:↓   1A:→   1B:←   1C:∟   1D:↔   1E:▲
1F:▼   20:    21:!   22:"   23:#   24:$   25:%   26:&   27:'   28:(
```

Notice how the colon is missing after `08` - a backspace, there is a long gap after `09` - a tab, and `0A` - a linefeed - has advanced the output by one line. You should be able to figure out what happened to `0D` by thinking about a "carriage return" on an old-fashioned typewriter.

If you wonder about why data is not displaying as you expect, you should go back to where it comes from, in this case outputting the value of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have non-printable characters. ASCII 0-31 may or may not print out a character as expected. Some include Backspace (which would remove a character), Tab, LineFeed, Bell, etc.